# Examples for certain class of projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, examples

I am looking for specific varieties that satisfy certain property. I call them symmetric varieties, I want to know what varieties are in it. It contains the projective spaces $\mathbb{P}^n$ for all $n$, but I don't know of any other examples. Let $X$ be smooth projective variety. There exists a codimension $2$ smooth subvariety $Z$ that is the intersection of hypersurface sections in $X$. The complement $U=X\setminus Z$ is constructed by gluing two affine schemes (Each affine scheme corresponds to the complement of the each of the two hypersurface sections). So let's call them $\text{Spec}(R_1)$ and $\text{Spec}(R_2)$. They are glued along an affine subscheme. This means there are $f\in R_1$ and $g\in R_2$ that $R_{1f}\cong R_{2g}$. Let's call this identification isomorphism $\phi$. We call $X$ symmetric if there is a choice of $Z, R_1, R_2$ such that $R_1$ is isomorphic to $R_2$ and this isomorphism coincides with $\phi$ on the localizations. (You could say the isomorphism $\phi$ extends to an isomorphism of $R_i$'s.)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Inside the function field $k(X)$, you have $R_{1f}\boldsymbol{=}R_{2g}$. An isomorphism $R_1\rightarrow R_2$ which coincides with the identity on localizations must be the identity.